# How to access an object created in one file in another class from anohter file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a quick numerical solver where all variables are shared among different files. Thus the Object containing the variables must be accessed by all files in the project.

This is a numerical application which solves the Laplace Equation. Unfortunately, my experience is basically on Fortran90 and MPI and nothing on OOP. I want to keep each "subroutine" isolated on each file. This is how I have developed codes with thousands of lines in CFD but in Fortran using procedural. I'd like to use the same idea but with objects.

```
file1.py
class Variables:
   def __init__():
      self.AnodeLength = 2.0
      self.CathodeLength = 1.0
      self.Length = 0.0
 ......
 #    a bunch of more variables

file2.py
from file1 import *

ME = Variables()
# ME is the object from the class Variables from file1.py and it contains all the variables needed for the computation.
GridSolver = Grid()
GridSolver.GridGeneration    #Here is the problem

file3.py
from file2 import *
class Grid:
    def GridGeneration(self):
        EM.Length = EM.AnodeLength + EM.CathodeLength
```

When I execute the previous code it gives me the error of EM is not recognized. I guess it makes sense because the EM is not in the scope of that class but in file2.py where I initiated.

1. Is there any option to pass an Object to a class as an argument? For example, If I could pass the object EM into the class Grid I could pull the attributes from that object inside the Grid Class and I think I could solve my problem.
2. Is it possible to make an object global such that every class (From every file) on the same directory can access that object?

Comment: One is called EM and the other is called ME. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current approach, yes you can **pass an Object to a class as an argument**. Your updated code will look like

***file1.py***

```
class Variables:
   def __init__():
      self.AnodeLength = 2.0
      self.CathodeLength = 1.0
      self.Length = 0.0
 ......
 #    a bunch of more variables
```

***file2.py***

```
from file1 import *

ME = Variables()
# ME is the object from the class Variables from file1.py and it contains all the variables needed for the computation.
GridSolver = Grid()
GridSolver.GridGeneration(ME)    #Passing the object as parameter
```

***file3.py***

```
from file2 import *
class Grid:
    def GridGeneration(self, EM):
        EM.Length = EM.AnodeLength + EM.CathodeLength
```

As you can see we have changed the GridGeneraion to accept an additional parameter.
Now let me show you the way all standard modules use constants.

***file1.py***

```
ANODE_LENGTH = 2.0
CATHODE_LENGTH = 1.0
LENGTH = 0.0
#  a bunch of more variables
```

***file2.py***

```
GridSolver = Grid()
GridSolver.GridGeneration()    # no need to pass parameter
```

***file3.py***

```
import file1
class Grid:
    def GridGeneration(self):
        EM.Length = file1.ANODE_LENGTH + file1.CATHODE_LENGTH
```

There is any issue with the above code, anyone can assign values to these constants. So in python, there is no constant. It means anyone can change values like this `ANODE_LENGTH=100`. Although, you can implement the constant implementation based on [this post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/)

so your ***file2.py*** implementation will change as below

```
class _file2:
    class ConstError(TypeError): pass
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(name):
            raise self.ConstError, "Can't rebind const(%s)"%name
        self.__dict__[name]=value
import sys
sys.modules[__name__]=_file2()
```